# How do I add a modified dll to the Global Assembly Cache?

Tags: .net, dll, gac, global-assembly-cache

I have the MySQL Connector/NET installed on my PC.  I modified the source code and recompiled one of the dlls (MySQL.Data.dll).  With the program already installed, how can add this dll to the Global Assembly Cache?

If your answer involves using gacutil.exe, please tell me where I can find it on my PC or where I might download it.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you control the client application that consumes that Connector?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure.  In the end, I'm writing a Silverlight App, but Entity Framework is what actual is consuming the connector (I think...there might be another layer of abstraction behind that that I'm not aware of). I think this is the flow: MySQL DB -> MySQL Connector/.Net -> Entity Framework - > RIA Services -> Silverlight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put it in the GAC but unless you have access to the private key with which it was originally signed, the installed program(s) will not recognize it.

Comment: I'm assuming the "private key" is different from the "public key token."  So is there any way to make my "custom" dll useable in the program?

Comment: I'm afraid not, what you want to do is something the signing was designed to prevent.

Comment: That makes sense.  It's still frustrating.  I'll keep digging for the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Open Windows Explorer (WindowsKey+E). Go to `c:\windows\assembly`. Open a second explorer window and drag and drop your assembly to the first window.

Answer (score 1):

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\gacutil.exe" /i "strongnamed.dll" /f /nologo
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple: Start-> Programs-> Microsoft Visual Studio 2005/2008 -> Visual Studio Tools -> 
Visual Studio 2005/2008 command prompt

a cmd appears, where you can type gacutil.

It also shows you the path where it resides:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC> on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Visual Studio Command Prompt

First open Visual Studio Command Prompt (For Visual Studio 2010 the path is Programs --> Visual Studio 2008 --> Visual Studio Tools --> Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt )
All the files mentioned in the following steps will be created in the Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt Path.

1. Generate a KeyFile 
   sn -k keyPair.snk
2. Get the MSIL for the assembly 
   ildasm SomeAssembly.dll /out:SomeAssembly.il
3. Rename the original assembly, just in case 
   ren SomeAssembly.dll SomeAssembly.dll.orig
4. Build a new assembly from the MSIL output and your KeyFile
   ilasm SomeAssembly.il /dll /key=keyPair.snk
5. Install the DLL in to the GAC
   gacutil -i SomeAssembly.dll